# Why not mock multiple axios call on same page using Jest in React Native?

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I am making two or more requests on same page, and it would be difficult to manage that with mock return values -- as well as brittle: if you re-arrange your page then your tests could fail because your return values were in the wrong order on your mock.

So, I am checking for any other way to mock return values in jest.

In React.js MSW tool is available to handle the above scenario but in React Native I didn't find such tool to handle above scenario

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your calling multiple axios.get Api calls on single page, then to avoid conflict you have to create separate function for each Api
e.g.
**1.first Api call**

const **firstCall**= jest.fn();

axios.get = firstCall.mockResolvedValueOnce(dummy_data).

**2.second Api call**

const **secondCall**= jest.fn();

axios.get = secondCall.mockResolvedValueOnce(dummy_data2).

If you do this, your test cases will work as expected.